# FlatList causing the js thread to not responding for a while

Tags: react-native

i recently faced a problem with `ReactNative` App.
i use `FlatList` to render a list of items. 
when my list get filled for the first time, ui thread get stuck for a while (about 5 sec).
when i press an item of my list 3 times (for example), _onPressItem will not be calling for a 5 secounds.
after 5 second, all of 3 times callback will called in a moment.

I use `FlatList` like the below

```
<FlatList
    onScroll={(event)=>this._onScroll}
    keyExtractor={item => item.uniqueKey}
    data={myData}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <ItemPackage
            flightPackage={item}
            onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
        />
    )}
    onEndReached={(x) => {}}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
    onEndReachedThreshold={50}
/>
```

my `ItemPackage` is like this

```
class ItemPackage extends React.Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        return false;
    }
    _onPress = () => {
        if (this.props.onPressItem)
            this.props.onPressItem(this.props.flightPackage);
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
                ...
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

i extend `ItemPackage` from `React.PureComponent`, but nothing changed (app stuck again).
i tested, and each `ItemPackage` rendering exactly one time (not more).

`myData` is an array that contains about 150 items.

is there any one, faced this problem before ?

Comment: have you tried using [`initialNumToRender`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#initialnumtorender)?

Comment: yes i tried it but problem not solved.

Comment: Any improvements on the response time though?

Comment: no any improvement

Comment: Do you have fixed height on your items? Also what else your ItemPackage component renders? Can you provide full sample please

Comment: yes. ItemPackages height is almost fixed

Comment: trying to use [`getItemLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#getitemlayout) might help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172808/discussion-between-sadegh-teimouri-and-bennygenel).

Comment: Facing same problem... any suggestions? I have a FlatList of variable height items, so I have implemented my own method to dynamically calculate the heights... Also, maxRenderPerBatch, windowSize, ... have values lower than the defaults.